# How to display a multicolumn ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an android application that shows a listview that shows:

one

two

three

four

But I want to show in the following format:

one        two

three      four

What should I do ？

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is the solution to your problem. Follow this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should maintain one separate xml file to display any kind of your output in a **listview** in Android.

For a multi column list view the xml file would be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- row.xml -->
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Here](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/) is the example what you are looking for. And for complete tutorial to implement multi column list view you can check [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/)

Good luck

Comment: I just give a simple example. The actual operation is more complicated. Well, how describe it? Is to use the listview to the functionality of the gridview. I know that can be achieved with gridview, but I want use lisview to achieve.

Comment: then you can implement in this way. first of all design your list row design and repeat it in a looping conditions. I am sure you will get your requirement if you follow this